# Cisco Meraki AD Authentication on iPads not working

Tags: windows-authentication, ipad, meraki

I've had Cisco Meraki setup for a while for our iPad MDM and it's been great.  I am now trying to take it a setup further by added in AD authentication at enrollment time.

I've followed [this how-to from Cisco Meraki](https://documentation.meraki.com/SM/Device_Enrollment/SM_Enrollment_Authentication), I'm using the thrid option `Active Directory via SM Agent`.

Everything seems to be ok from the Meraki point of view. I get the green check mark next to the domain controller I just added under the status column.

On the iPad, when enrolling, it asks for a username and password, but whatever combo of username, email address etc that I try does not work.

Windows firewall is off on the servers and I've double checked the Firewall Information page from Meraki.  All my required ports seem to be correctly opened.  I also get a good connection status of the windows server in the Meraki client console.

I am missing a step?

Comment: Have you tried domain\user, user@domain, and user?

Comment: Yes i have tried all those combo's

Comment: Did you set the AD server as the gateway?

Comment: Yes, so I installed the SM agent on the AD server, the server then showed up in my client list and I was able to select it as the gateway.  The only thing that I was unsure about was the IP address.  I used my internal IP address which is behind a firewall.

Comment: Yes, the IP address should be the private IP address of your DC.

Comment: All add a screen shot in my question.  I have used the private IP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40681/discussion-between-user5870571-and-tyelford).

Comment: Is the iPad maybe prompting for the iCloud username and password, rather than the Meraki/AD credentials?

Comment: https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/Splash_Page/Troubleshooting_Active_Directory_Authentication_with_Sign-on_Splash_Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others who run into a problem with Meraki mobile enrollment please see this answer and the complete discussion that led to this solution http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40681/discussion-between-user5870571-and-tyelford.

On the User Authentication Settings page make sure that the username is entered as domain\user and the port number is 3268.

Because Meraki does not encrypt the traffic from the gateway machine to AD it is best if you install the gateway client on AD.

The domain controller needs to be a Global Catalog that is why the server port is 3268 and not 389.

When the user logs into the Meraki they will use user@domain for their username.